# Paste two files to the first file

Tags: bash, file, unix, command-line, concatenation

We have below two files:

*t1.txt*

```
1
2
3
```

*t2.txt*

```
a
s
d
```

I could use:

```
paste -d"," t1.txt t2.txt > result.txt
```

and output *result.txt*

```
1,a
2,s
3,d
```

Which is perfect, but I want to do below:

```
paste -d"," t1.txt t2.txt > t1.txt
```

and I was expecting *t1.txt* to be same as *result.txt*, but it is as below, not as I need:

```
,a
,s
,d
```

I could just rename *result.txt* to *t1.txt*, but wondering if there is a better way?

**Note:**

- Solution doesn't have to be `paste`, can be anything as long as we avoid creating temporary file like *result.txt*.
- Actual *t1.txt* and *t2.txt* files have 1.6 million rows each.

Comment: I suggest: `paste -d"," t1.txt t2.txt > result.txt && mv result.txt t1.txt`

Comment: _"as long as we avoid creating temporary file like result.txt."_  It depends on what you mean by that.  Since the data from the new and old files have to both exist during processing. the temporary results will have to be stored somewhere, whether in memory or on disk.

Comment: @John1024 Good point, I think I am OK with temp files. My concern is, this will be run in parallel so `result.txt` file should be run specific, maybe using `mktemp`?

Comment: @zx8754 Is `mktemp` installed on your system?  If not, it is usually good enough to use: `paste -d, t1.txt t2.txt > ~/result$$.txt && mv ~/result$$.txt t1.txt`

Comment: @John1024 Please post an answer with `$$` and `mktemp`, in the meantime I will test get back to you, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using sponge

The `sponge` utility was created just for this task:

```
paste -d, t1.txt t2.txt | sponge t1.txt
```

`sponge` is part of the `moreutils` package.  On debian/ubuntu-like systems, run `apt-get install moreutils`.

#### Using mktemp

```
fname=$(mktemp) && paste -d, t1.txt t2.txt >>"$fname" && mv "$fname" t1.txt
```

#### Using a temporary file (without mktemp)

If one doesn't have access to either `mktemp` or `sponge`, one can use:

```
paste -d, t1.txt t2.txt > ~/result$$.txt && mv ~/result$$.txt t1.txt
```

You have a choice of where to put the temporary file.  In the above, we put it in the user's home directory, `~/`, because this avoids the security issues that come from putting files in directories like `/tmp`.

`$$` is the process ID.  This is expected to be unique at least for the life of the process.

Comment: I am afraid, I don't have privileges to install.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the first file disappears is this:

```
paste -d"," t1.txt t2.txt > t1.txt
```

1. The shell process the redirection first, truncating the "t1" file in preparation to receive data. **The file is now empty**
2. Now the shell invokes the command with one empty file.

See Section 3.7.1 in the bash manual inder https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Executing-Commands